# C pointer wrong value?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm still learning C. I've implemented a simple word guess program. 
While playing with debug I saw that my pointer actually points true memory value but when I initialize a char array(different one), the pointer that points other char array is also initialized.
Here is the beginning of code:

```
char *theword = pickAWord();//returns a word from .dat file
char guess[40]; //guess = 0x003afa94 
char guessedWord[20]; //guessedWord = 0x003afa78 
char play_again;
char *guessedWordp = guessedWord; //guessedWordp = 0x003afa78

int guessedWordIndex = 0;
int a = strlen(theword)-1;
int found = 0;
int *foundp = &found;
int *hakp = &hak;
int *guessedWordIndexp = &guessedWordIndex;
```

When I initialize guess char array like this:

```
for(i=0; i<a; i++){
    guess[i*2] = '_';
    guess[i*2+1] = ' ';
    if(i==a-1) guess[i*2+1] = '\0';
}
```

Suddenly, *guessedWordp pointer and array values changes like this:

```
guessedWordp = 0x003afa78 "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ_ _ _ _ _ _ _"
guessedWord = 0x003afa78 "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ_ _ _ _ _ _ _"
```

I'm just curious that why "_ _ _ _ _ _ _" this added at the end of the guessedWordp pointer when i actually initialize it to guess char array (guess array corretly initialized with corret value by the way)

I'm using visual studio 2010

Comment: Two things stand out as important, and are not provided with this code: 1) How does `pickAWord()` allocate the return string who's address is saved in `theWord`, and 2) What guarantees do you have the returned word is fewer than 20 chars long? Elsewhere, the `if` block in the `for` loop is not needed, as what you're *trying* to do can be accomplished *after* the loop. And I'm somewhat leery to even ask how `play_again` is used later.

Comment: 1-) return value address is diff from others. 2-) the words in the document are below 20 char long. If i don't add the if block in for, the value of guess is guess = 0x002afaa8 "_ _ _ ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌHÅ" like that. Means that the char array is never ends because of there is no '\0'. I dont know what cause that actually as i'm new in c. play_again is used like this at the end of game if(play_again == 'y') goto play;

Comment: OK. The terminator in (2) can be set after the for-loop. You know where `i` ended (`a`), so `guess[2*a -1] = 0` after the loop is sufficient. Check the math and see. And for `play_again` it wasn't so much how you *evaluate* it I was leery of, it was more how you *populate* it.

Comment: You are right about at (2). it is a cursorily code. Just to learn how to things work in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ignore it, it's meaningless. You haven't initialized `guessedWord`, and that's what `guessedWordp` points to. So the contents are entirely meaningless.

If you like, add `guessedWord[0] = 0;` to initialize `guessedWord` to an empty string and the mystery will go away.

Comment: +1 Sometimes I can't see the forest for the trees. Really well done picking through this.